# The laminal and apical sibilants in Spanish: Where can I get some good recordings?

Tags: diferencias-regionales, pronunciación, dialectos

Primero mi pregunta en español:

**Los sibilantes laminales y apicales en español: ¿Dónde puedo conseguir algunas buenas grabaciones?**

**Details in English:**

I've been a student of Spanish for some time now and recently I've been trying to take my listening, speaking, and pronunciation skills to another level.  I try to listen to a variety of Spanish dialects and in the course of my exploration of this language came across something that discussed the laminal sibilant or [**laminal consonant**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laminal_consonant) and the apical sibilant or [**apical consonant**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apical_consonant).  Since then, I've attempted to find recordings of each of these sounds, but have not been able to find any.

I've read that the laminal is the English "s," and I'm assuming that the apical is more like the "th" sound in the word "thin," but whenever I listen to the Spanish spoken by some Spaniards, even the "s" (in words such as "sabes," "señor," "cosas," et cetera) doesn't always sound exactly like the "s" in English.  Compare the following:

[**sofas**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2phhZixkhp8)

with:

[**cosas**](https://forvo.com/word/cosas/#es)

In the recordings of “cosas,” listen to the pronunciation of reality3d and then the one by runnernet.  It sounds as if the “s” pronounced by reality3d closely approximates the “s” used in English, but the one by runnernet sounds a bit different to me.

Most of the time, however, the “s” in English and the “s” in Spanish sound virtually the same to me, especially if the “s” starts the word.

Furthermore, the "th" sound (in words such as "entonces," "decir," "cerveza," et cetera) sounds a bit different as well.  To me, it sounds as if more air is used when pronouncing words with "ci," "ce," or "z."  Is this an accurate observation of the Spanish (as spoken by some Spaniards)?

**Examples with audio:**

In this first example (listen to the one by Sento pronouncing "entonces"), it almost sounds as if the “th” is a mix of the “s” and the “th” sound, whereas in English, you almost don’t even hear any air in the pronunciation of “th” and when it is clearly audible, it seems to be completely devoid of any “s” sound.

Compare [**forthcoming**](https://forvo.com/word/forthcoming/#en) with [**entonces.**](https://forvo.com/word/entonces/#es)

**More audio examples:**

Compare [**author**](https://forvo.com/word/author/#en) with [**decir.**](https://forvo.com/word/decir/#es)

Compare [**thermal**](https://forvo.com/word/thermal/#en) with [**cerveza.**](https://forvo.com/word/cerveza/#es)

Trying to distinguish the differences between regional variations is one thing, but trying to distinguish between the subtle differences in subregional variations that might vary from town to town or even family to family is very difficult to draw accurate conclusions from and use as a base of comparison to try to improve my own pronunciation.

If I were to be able to find some good recordings of experts pronouncing the laminal sibilant and the apical sibilant, emphasizing the difference between those two along with a description (or even better a video) of the physiology used in each (i.e., mouth shape, tongue placement), I think it would really help me (and others) utter these sounds with more confidence.  Anybody know where I can find some good recordings of these sounds?

By the way, in my search for such recordings, I came across the following from the Wikipedia entry on [**Spanish dialects and varieties**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_dialects_and_varieties):

[**Variants of /s/**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_dialects_and_varieties#Variants_of_.2Fs.2F)

[**Debuccalization of coda /s/**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_dialects_and_varieties#Debuccalization_of_coda_.2Fs.2F)

Though I found the page very informative and recommend reading it, none of the descriptions of pronunciation appear to link up to any page containing audio of the specific examples.

As always, thanks in advance for your answers.

**Detalles en español:**

He sido estudiante de español desde hace ya algún tiempo y recientemente, he estado tratando de llevar mis habilidades de escuchar, de hablar y de pronunciar a otro nivel.  Trato de escuchar a una variedad de dialectos españoles y en el curso de mi exploración de esta lengua, me encontré con algo que mencionó el sibilante o [**consonante laminal**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consonante_laminar) y el sibilante o [**consonante apical**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consonante_apical).  Desde entonces, he intentado de encontrar grabaciones de cada uno de estos sonidos, pero no he sido capaz de encontrar ninguno.

He leído que el laminal es la “s” de inglés, y estoy asumiendo que el apical es más como el sonido de “th” en la palabra “thin”, pero cada vez que escucho al español hablado por algunos españoles, aún la “s” (en palabras como “sabes”, “señor”, “cosas”, et cetera) no siempre suena exactamente como la “s” en inglés.

[Véanse la sección en inglés por las grabaciones de audio.]

En las grabaciones de “cosas”, escuchen a la pronunciación de reality3d y entonces la de runnernet.  Suena como si la “s” pronunciada por reality3d más se aproxima la “s” usada en inglés, pero la de por runnernet suena un poco diferente a mí.

La mayoría del tiempo, sin embargo, la “s” en inglés y la “s” en español suena virtualmente la misma a mí, especialmente si la “s” es la primera letra de la palabra.

Además, el sonido de “th”, (en palabras como “entonces”, “decir”, “cerveza”, et cetera) también suena un poco diferente.  A mí, suena como más aire se usa al pronunciar palabras con “ci”, “ce”, or “z”.  ¿Es esta una observación correcta del español (como hablado por algunos españoles)?

**Algunos ejemplos más:**

En este primer ejemplo (escuche al uno por Sento pronunciando "entonces"), casi suena como el “th” es una mezcla de la “s” y el sonido de “th”, mientras que en inglés, casi ni siquiera se oye nada de aire en la pronunciación de “th” y cuando es claramente audible, parece ser totalmente carente del sonido de la “s.”

[Véanse la sección en inglés por las grabaciones de audio.]

Tratando de distinguir las diferencias entre variaciones regionales es una cosa, pero tratando de distinguir entre las diferencias sútiles en variaciones subregionales que podrían variar de pueblo a pueblo o aún familia a familia es muy difícil de que extraer conclusiones exactas y usar como una base de comparación para tratar de mejorar mi propia pronunciación.

Si yo fuera capaz de oír unas buenas grabaciones de expertos pronunciando el sibilante “s” (laminal) y el sibilante “s” (apical), destacando la diferencia entre estos dos junto con una descripción (o aún mejor un video) de la fisiología utilizada en cada uno (es decir, forma de la boca, la colocación de la lengua), creo que realmente me ayudaría (y otros) a pronunciar estos sonidos con más confianza.  ¿Alguien sabe dónde puedo encontrar algunas buenas grabaciones de estos sonidos?

De todos modos, en mi búsqueda por esas grabaciones, me topé con el siguiente de la entrada de Wikipedia en [**Spanish dialects and varieties**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_dialects_and_varieties):

[Véanse la sección en inglés por los enlaces.]

Aunque la página es muy informativa y recomiendo que se lea, ningunas de las descripciones de pronunciación parece que vincular a cualquier página conteniendo audio de los ejemplos específicos.

Como siempre, gracias de antemano por sus respuestas.

Comment: The apical shouldn't sound anything like an English *th* (IPA: [ð] or [θ]) , if anything it should most closely resemble the English *sh* (IPA: [ʃ].  Different Spanish speakers in Spain will vary between a more laminal or apical pronunciation, even for the same person.  The current prime minister is notorious for his exceptionally apical pronunciation.  Note, however, that the sound produced by a *ce, ci* or *z* is virtually identical to the *th* in English's *thistle* (IPA: [θ])

Comment: The only aspect of this that I can weigh in on is the Peruvian speaker pronouncing *cosas*.  I know people from Peru and and I'm familiar with what he's doing there.  He's sitting longer on the final S than the average Spanish speaker does.  It's just a cultural difference.  I wouldn't get hung up on that particular peculiarity.  Also I think that for Latin American Spanish the most important things, to achieve a beautiful accent, are, first, pure vowels and the absence of glottal stops; second, fairly equal syllables (I've seen this described as the rat-a-tat-tat of a machine gun); ...

Comment: ... absence of air (aspiration) for hard c, p, t; and a flapped r and a rolled rr.  Please feel free to record a short poem and post it in la Tertulia for feedback.  Don't forget to ping me because I don't go there regularly.

Comment: @aparente001  I'll be sure to take you up on your offer.  I've never really had anyone give me a detailed, specific critique of my pronunciation.  I don't think it's so bad that it impedes understanding, but whenever I've been around native speakers, I know I don't sound like they do.  I'd really love to more closely approximate the pronunciation of a native speaker.  I don't know if that's possible, but I definitely feel that there are other things I could be doing (than what I'm doing now) to take it to another level.  I just don't know what they are.  Looking forward to your help!

Comment: @guifa  Thank you for your feedback.  If you're wondering where I got these notions about the laminant and apical, this thread here is what launched my inquiry:[**Castilian "Lisp" [ ceceo/seseo ]**] (https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/castilian-lisp-ceceo-seseo.280996/?hl=es)  After rereading portions of the thread, I see now that I had remembered some details of it incorrectly.  Thank you for correcting me.

Comment: @LisaBeck - Two ideas.  One, you record yourself reading a couple paragraphs or a fun poem, and you post a link to the text and one to the recording.  There are places to upload temporary sound files -- sorry I don't remember where right now.  Or two, you open a chat room, share your email address, I copy it down, notify you I've got it, and then you delete your comment.  If you're going to do this, I suggest you let me know what day and time you're going to post it, so you can delete it quickly.

Comment: To what @aparente001 said about important things I would add proper lenition (fricativization) of the medial voiced stops /b/, /d/ and /g/ (that goes hand in hand with un-aspirated voiceless stops).

Comment: @pablodf76 - Not sure what you mean about /b/ and /g/.  Certainly T and D are different between the two languages but those sounds don't grate on my nerves as much as the other things.  I wasn't trying to make a complete list of differences....  What are your pet peeves?

Comment: @aparente001 I mean the fact that Spanish voiced stops between vowels and after some consonants are realized as fricatives or even approximants, so it's noticeable when non-natives pronounce them as stops. It might not be that much, or it might make a medial /b/ sound a bit like a /p/, because we associate a (phonetic) medial stop with (phonemic) voicelessness.

Comment: @pablodf76 - Thanks for explaining. // And your pet pronunciation peeves?

Comment: @aparente001 I can't think of any (in Spanish), really, I don't have that much experience with foreign language speakers trying to master oral Spanish.

Comment: @pablodf76 - Oh.  I noticed at https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2587/9385 that you don't appear to have substantial experience living in an English-speaking country (why don't you make yourself a profile, by the way?).  How the heck did your English get so good?

Comment: @aparente001  Now that I've done a search for "la Tertulia" I'm guessing you weren't referring to a specific site.  Either way, if you've got a link to what you were referring to, add it to this thread and I'll check it out.  Otherwise, I would suggest this site called [**Hellolingo**](https://www.hellolingo.com/).  It's probably not the only site that does this, but in its chat rooms, you can opt to send a voice recording instead of a text.  However, it distorts your voice, which is quite cool for privacy reasons, but I don't know how well this helps identify micro flaws in pronunciation.

Comment: @aparente001  Then again, it is rather presumptuous of me to think that my flaws would be hidden with a mere altering of pitch.  I'm curious as to why you keep suggesting a poem, though.  Isn't it possible that one's reading of a poem might differ somewhat from regular text (e.g., the type found in a book or newspaper article)?

Comment: @pablodf76  I almost feel as if I've been caught up in a rip tide of linguistic thought!  Help!  I need a lifeguard!  Seriously though, after some web surfing, I now have a vague notional idea of what a "medial voiced stop" is, but examples of particular words would be helpful.  In fact, hearing an overly exaggerated poor pronunciation by an English speaker and then a flawless pronunciation by a native would be even more helpful.  Even better?  Adding a speech waveform to both with side to side viewing.  Anyone reading this able to make a YouTube video with a speech waveform for each?

Comment: @LisaBeck - Sorry.  La Tertulia is our nickname for the chat room here.  If you click on the top right corner of the screen ("Current Community") you'll see "Chat."  Click on that.  Probably best to invite me to a new room since La Tertulia fills up with this, that and the other.  But you're also welcome there.  (I don't visit it often myself due to lack of time.)  // On second thought I'm going to invite you to a room now myself, that will make things easier.

Comment: @LisaBeck I'll try and do that. Can't promise anything. Speech waveforms won't help, though, I think.

Comment: @pablodf76 Speech waveforms won't help?  Interesting.  I'm not discounting what your comment, but what makes you say that?

Comment: @aparente001 I checked out Tertulia (the chat room here).  I knew StackExchange had some chat rooms and I had been meaning to explore them a bit.  I thought that maybe if I ever absolutely had to have a question answered as quickly as possible, they might be helpful, but they're a bit hit and miss in general.  It kind of really all depends who's on it at any given time.  Plus, I don't see any opp to share voice recordings, like you can over at Hellolingo.  Thanks for mentioning it, though.  I'll check it out from time to time.

Comment: I don't think speech waveforms would be useful for someone that is not a specialist in reading them, or, in any case, they wouldn't be useful to explain to someone how to place their vocal organs for the production of a given sound.

Comment: @LisaBeck - Welcome back! // For me to notice something in la Tertulia, you really must ping me.  // What happened with the room I created for you to share a way for us to get in touch directly?  Did you not receive the invitation to join?  That room is closed now, apparently.  I can't find it any more.  You're welcome to open one and invite me.  To play it safe, I suggest you ping me here as well. // Take a look at https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/423742/how-to-pronounce-the-singular-irishman-and-the-plural-irishmen?noredirect=1#comment1015079_423742. Do you see how an anonymous...

Comment: ...sound clip was shared? You are welcome to do that in la Tertulia but if you want to limit it to just those who are interested (I believe pablo was also game), I suggest creating a separate room.  // If you've found a site where the software facilitates the recording, sharing, and feedback process, just give me a link and I'll join you there.  I've never used hellolingo but I'm game to give it a try.

Comment: Re waveforms.  The recording my friend and I made today was done in audacity, and one can see waveforms there.  If you are curious what your waveforms and mine look like, we can share the native audacity files (aup file type) without converting to mp3.

Comment: @aparente001  No, I never received an invitation to join your chat room (or, I don't think I did).  For some reason, I can't access Chrome right now.  Do I need to be using Chrome to receive an invitation?  In what way would such an invitation come to my attention?  Thanks for the links.  I'll take a look at them.

Comment: @aparente001 Just checked out the link and listened to the clip.  I really love that there's people out there observing and analyzing the nitty gritty particulars of pronunciation.  It appears that some experience the sound of language the way some experience the taste of wine.  In oenology, you have your sommeliers whose livelihood depends on training and developing their palate.  I don't know what the equivalent of a Master Sommelier would be in Linguistics, but some certainly have a more highly trained ear than others.  Very interesting.  Thanks for sending me the link.

Comment: @LisaBeck - I could create another room and invite you again, but actually I think our best chance of success is if you create a room and invite me.  That way you're the active party.  If you have any trouble ping me here and I'll do it and this time I'll ping you in both places.